# OS X: prevent Finder/File Chooser from following directory symlinks

Tags: macos, finder, symbolic-link

I have a have a symlink `foo` in `/Users/myaccount` which points to `/Volumes/foo`. In the Finder or file chooser, the symlink does not show up as directory, so I can't expand it to select `/Users/myaccount/foo/bar`, but instead I have to double click it which then let's my select `/Volumes/foo/bar`.

How to tell the Finder or file chooser that it should directory symlinks like directories, so I can expand them?

Comment: Actually, it should do so – that is Finder’s default behavior (just tested to be certain) since at least OS X 10.6 (not sure about 10.5). What do you mean exactly by “expand”? Does it display as a folder in column mode? Does `ls -l /Users/myaccount` show a valid link destination (the part after the `->`)?

Comment: My valid directory symlinks show up in the Finder's column mode as "files", not as directories (though they have child directories). I'm using OS X 10.6 and 10.7.

Comment: Could you please post the result of `ls -l /Users/myaccount`? I just tested again on my system, and it works fine even with ejectable media that gets unmounted between accesses, at least on Lion… Also, your OS X version and a screenshot of the Finder window would be very helpful too!

Comment: `ls -l /Users/myaccount` returns `lrwxr-xr-x  1 mike  staff  29 Jan 24  2011 foo -> /Volumes/foo`

Comment: That looks correct. What kind of mount is `/Volumes/foo` (network? what protocol? local? what kind? DMG?)?

Comment: It's a mounted true crypt volume, but also happens for normal partitions.

Comment: And `mike`’s account is = `myaccount`?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: What does `ls -l /Volumes` return (when `foo` is mounted)?

Comment: It prints (among others) `drwxr-xr-x  12 mike  staff    476 Jul 27 10:17 foo`.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem with symlinks pointing to a samba mounted volume. Rebooting and remounting the volume solved the problem.